Next.js Cognito authentcation API works locally, but does not work when deployed to AWS with AWS CDK
I'm currently building a Next.js app (App router) which I deployed through AWS CDK with the cdk-nextjs-standalone construct. This is my CDK stack:
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Nextjs } from 'cdk-nextjs-standalone';

export class PresentoloB2BStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const nextjs = new Nextjs(this, 'Nextjs', {
      nextjsPath: '../',
      environment: {
        COGNITO_CLIENT_ID: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID || '',
        AUTH_SECRET: process.env.AUTH_SECRET || ''
      }
    });

    const userPool = new cdk.aws_cognito.UserPool(this, 'myuserpool', {
      userPoolName: 'PresentoloB2B-userpool',
      signInCaseSensitive: false, // case insensitive is preferred in most situations
      selfSignUpEnabled: false,
      autoVerify: { email: true },
      userInvitation: {
        emailSubject: 'We have set up a new account for you',
        emailBody: 'Hello {username}, thank you for choosing us! We have set up a new account for you. Your temporary password is {####}',
      },
      signInAliases: {
        username: true,
        email: true,
      },
      passwordPolicy: {
        minLength: 8,
        requireLowercase: true,
        requireUppercase: true,
        requireDigits: true,
        requireSymbols: true,
      },
      accountRecovery: cdk.aws_cognito.AccountRecovery.EMAIL_ONLY,
    });

    // Add UserPoolClient
    const userPoolClient = userPool.addClient('userpoolclient', {
      userPoolClientName: 'PresentoloB2B-client',
      authFlows: {
        userPassword: true,
        custom: true,
        userSrp: true,
      },
      supportedIdentityProviders: [
        cdk.aws_cognito.UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.COGNITO,
      ],
      preventUserExistenceErrors: true,
      accessTokenValidity: cdk.Duration.days(1),
      idTokenValidity: cdk.Duration.days(1),
      refreshTokenValidity: cdk.Duration.days(30),
      enableTokenRevocation: true,
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "CloudFrontDistributionDomain", {
      value: nextjs.distribution.distributionDomain,
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "UserPoolId", {
      value: userPool.userPoolId,
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "UserPoolClientId", {
      value: userPoolClient.userPoolClientId,
    });
  }
}

Now I got the following problem, that I can't resolve: As you can see in my cdk stack, my app uses AWS Cognito for authentication. Therefore, I have this auth.js file:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import process from 'process'

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
          username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "Username" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

        if (!credentials) return null;

        const params = {
            AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            AuthParameters: {
                USERNAME: credentials.username,
                PASSWORD: credentials.password, // Use raw password
            },
        };

        try {
            const response = await cognito.initiateAuth(params).promise();
            console.log('Cognito response:', response); // Log the response
            const user = {
                id: response.AuthenticationResult?.AccessToken,
                name: credentials.username,
            };
            return user;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Detailed Cognito error:', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            if (error.code === 'NotAuthorizedException') {
                // Invalid username or password
                throw new Error('Invalid username or password');
            }
            throw error; // Rethrow other errors
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
})

This auth.js file is used as an API under src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:
import { handlers } from "../../../../../auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers

This API gets used as follows:
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';

// some code

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await setLoading(true);
            const result = await signIn('credentials', {
                redirect: false,
                username,
                password,
            });

            await setLoading(false);

            if (result.error) {
                setError(true);
            } else {
                // Redirect to dashboard or home page
                window.location.href = '/u/generate';
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError(translations.login_error);
        }
    }

//some other code

Here is the weird thing: For some reason, this Login-functionality only works locally (with npm run dev). As soon as I try to use this Login-functionality within the deployed (accessible through an AWS CloudFront URL) version, I get redirected to a 500 Internal Server Error page under https://XXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net/api/auth/error. I have configured my environment variables in .env and .env.local. Would highly appreciate your help!

This is just a guess but some time ago I was trying to deploy a Nuxt (Vue) static website (hosted on S3 and CloudFront) with Cognito authentication and had a similar problem. Everything worked locally but once deployed, the authentication process was failing. Open the developer console and see if your requests aren't blocked by CORS.
I had to explicitly add Cognito to the S3 bucket's CORS policy.
Resources:
  WebsiteBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
          - AllowedMethods:
              - POST
            AllowedOrigins:
              - cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
            AllowedHeaders:
              - "*"


I tried to hardcode the cognito client id instead of setting it as environment variable, but the error still remains. I also added the following to my userPoolClient configuration within the AWS CDK stack, but it also didn't solve the issue. Or is there another way to set CORS for cognito in my case?:
     oAuth: {         callbackUrls: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://XXXXX.cloudfront.net'],         logoutUrls: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://XXXXX.cloudfront.net'],         flows: {           authorizationCodeGrant: true,         },       }, 

What I mentioned is a CORS policy for the S3 bucket, not Cognito.
It would be helpful if you could check requests information in the developer console within your browser. That could tell you a little bit more about why it fails.
